# Error:(31, 32) error: cannot find symbol class AuthCredential

Tags: android, firebase

Cannot import the following when working with firebase

```
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
```

Gradle File

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

Is i need anything extra to add to compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add all fire base dependencies with same version and you have added `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'` dependency it may getting ambiguity with old dependency so remove it and try to add the new dependencies  and sync the project.
here are the latest dependencies available from fire base.

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0     Analytics
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0     Realtime Database
com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.0  Storage
com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0    Crash Reporting
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0     Authentication
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0    Cloud Messaging and Notifications
com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.0   Remote Config
com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.6.0  Invites and Dynamic Links
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0  AdMob
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.0  App Indexing
```

for more reference  [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)